# Access SQLite database from WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, sqlite, webview

I am developing an Android app and my plan is to show to the user a WebView, since it is easier for me to code in HTML. This app is supposed to maintain some information.

In theory, I should use a native approach connecting my app to a SQLite database. Since I would like to use a WebView, I am looking for some methods to access the database from the WebView directly.

Is it possible to access a SQLite database from a WebView? Is there any alternative that I can use to create a app using HTML?

Comment: Do you want to use SQLite to store some local file html?

Comment: No, I have to store some data. Then I should be able to add, edit and delete data from the HTML file.

Answer (score -1):

> 1.First of all make class that extend SQLiteOpenHelper
>
> 2.Create a contractor for that class and implement all the function that needed .
>
> On the method onCreate((SQLiteDatabasedb)
>
> Just create String called query and create the table you want , and
>   execSql it , for example :
>
> String query="create table if not exists table(text text,name
>   text2,_id text)"; db.execSQL(query); Then for create new row in the
>   sql lite use :

```
public void add_new_row(String text,String text2,String _id){ try{
ContentValues cn=new ContentValues();  cn.put("text",per_name); 
cn.put("text2",per_age);       cn.put("_id",per_age);      

SQLiteDatabase db;      db=getWritableDatabase();   
db.insert("table",null,cn);} catch(Exception e){
Log.i("AddSql_lite","Print :"+e.to );

 } And for read Row from sqllite you just use :

public String getRow_by_id(String _id){ string text = ""; try{
   db=getWritableDatabase(); query="select * from table where _id =
   '"+_id+"'";

     Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(query, null);
     if(cr.moveToFirst()){
         do{
             text = cr.getString(0);
             String text2 = cr.getString(1);
             String _id = cr.getString(2);
         }while(cr.moveToNext());
     }

 }catch(Exception e){
 }

 return text; } And for reading all the rows in the table one after another :

public int get_all_Rows(){ string int counter = 0; try{
db=getWritableDatabase(); query="select * from table";

     Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(query, null);
     if(cr.moveToFirst()){
         do{
             text = cr.getString(0);
             String text2 = cr.getString(1);
             String _id = cr.getString(2);
             counter++;
         }while(cr.moveToNext());
     }

 }catch(Exception e){
 }

 return counter; } Hope its will help you to understand how Sqllite work and how build it correctly :)
```

And for make it run so just :

```
SQLiteDataBase Sqllite_ref = new SQLiteDataBase(context, "VerName",
null, 1);

Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey","hey4","1");
Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey2","hey5","2");
Sqllite_ref.add_new_row("hey3","hey6","3");

Sqllite_ref.getRow_by_id("2");>>> will return "hey2"
Sqllite_ref.get_all_Rows()>>> will return 3 [number of items you have
in the sqllite]
```